# Складывание слишком больших чисел с++

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Складываю 2 числа
111111111111111111111 + 888888888888888888888 через тип данных unsigned long long. Компилятор после сложения выдает -3. Есть другие способы сложения таких чисел?

Comment: а как именно вы понимаете алгоритм?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=vs-2019

Comment: вопрос в другом, как складывать тогда такие большие числа.

Answer (score 2):

Размер вашего результата не вмещается в нужный тип, поэтому для беззнаковых чисел происходит wrap around, т.е. после максимального числа идёт снова `0` и так далее по модулю. Для знаковых получаете неопределённое поведение.

Но у вас не только сумма не вмещается, но и даже слагаемые, поэтому программа ill-formed, если, конечно, нет расширения компилятора, которое поддерживает более широкие типы.

В любом случае, обе проблемы решаются использованием длинной арифметики. Есть куча библиотек для них, но можете и сами реализовать [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Длинная_арифметика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

Есть другие способы сложения таких чисел. Например тут смотрите http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_integers_(included)